# Стоит ли кэшировать GetComponent<>() при столкновениях?

Tags: unity3d, оптимизация

Обыкновенное кэширование допустим выглядит так :

```
private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }
```

и теперь я могу использовать это `rb` вместо `GetComponent<Rigidbody> ()` каждый раз, когда мне нужно получить доступ к компоненту. Но что делать, если у меня

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("SomeTag")) {

            if (other.GetComponent<SomeScript> ().someInt == 4) {
                other.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().mass = 12;
other.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().size = new Vector3 (10, 10, 0);
        }
```

?

```
 public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("SomeTag")) {
            Rigidbody rb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
            BoxCollider bc = other.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
            SomeScript ss = other.gameObject.GetComponent<SomeScript> ();


            if (ss.someInt == 4) {
                rb.mass = 12;
                bc.size = new Vector3 (10, 10, 0);
                ss.SomeVoidFunction ();
                // использую их вместо GetComponent<..>();
            }
    }
```

Есть ли смысл делать так или разницы нет вообще? Просто такое же будет происходить при каждом контакте с объектом и, так как он каждый раз будет "перекэшировать", то разницы вообще не будет (ну это мне так кажется). Так ли это или все же лучше кэшировать?

---

Обновление:

В идеале, конечно, хотелось бы закэшировать все это в самом объекте, с которым происходит столкновение, но тогда у моего объекта нет доступа к этим компонентам:

```
// это скрипт на объекте, с которым сталкивается мой объект
public class SomeObjectScript: MonoBehaviour {
public Rigidbody rb;
public BoxCollider bc;
public SomeObjectScript so; // для доступа к этому скрипту. Как вариант (но так тоже не выходит:
/*
    private static SomeObjectScript instance;
    public static SomeObjectScript Instance 
    {
        get {
            if (instance == null) 
            {
                instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<SomeObjectScript> ();
            }
            return SomeObjectScript.instance; }
    }
    */

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        bc = GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        so = GetComponent<SomeObjectScript> ();
    }
}

// это скрипт на моем объекте
public class MyObjectScript: MonoBehaviour {
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("SomeTag")) {

            if (other.gameObject.so.someInt == 4) {
                other.gameObject.rb.mass = 12;
                other.gameObject.bc.size = new Vector3 (10, 10, 0);
        }
```

Тут нет доступа к компонентам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете создать специальный класс-менеджер, который будет обрабатывать коллизии. В нем вы можете хранить ссылки на все объекты, которые будут сталкиваться. Предположим вы назовете их `CollidableObject`. В самом же классе `CollidableObject` вы можете закэшировать нужные вам поля, по типу Rigitbody и различных коллаидров в методе `Start()`, как описали в вопросе. К тому же у вас будет возможность сделать CollidableObject более безопасным к тому, чтобы забыть добавить какой-либо комнпонент, воспользовавшись атрибутом [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html). Далее в событии`OnTriggerEnter` вы можете запускать специальный ивент, передавая в него как параметры сам объект, который получил это сообщение и объект с которым он столкнулся. У объекта, с которым произошло столкновение вам понадобится только один раз вызвать `GetComponent<CollidableObject>()` и передать его в ваш ивен. Сам же ивет может слушать ваш класс-менеждер, который и будет обрабатывать действия, которые нужно совершить при столкновении.

Во-первых делая так вы сэкономите на вызовах `GetComponent<>()`, а во-вторых, сделаете свою архитектуру чище, за счет того, что вынесете логику обработки столкновения в отдельный класс (в вашем случае получается грязное решение - один объект напрямую меняет состояние компонентов другого, хотя по уму не должен ничего об этом знать)

Comment: мне нужно будет делать массив `BoxCollider bc []` (ну, к примеру), или хватит простого `bc` ("..в методе Start(), как описали в вопросе")? Просто я еще не делал отдельного класса для столкновений и пока не очень представляю, как подступиться к нему

Comment: Если делать, как я описал в ответе, то в классе-менеджере вам понадобится List<CollidableObject> collidable, и вы сможете сохранить в этот массив все объекты, которые могут сталкиваться. А у каждого CollidableObject будут поля по типу BoxCollider bc, Rigitbody rb. В методе Start() у каждого CollidableObject вы сможете сохранить эти компоненты.